# TypeScript array of union vs union of array

Tags: typescript, union-types

The TypeScript compiler are behaving differently if I have an union of arrays vs array of union:

```
type A = { x: string };
type B = { x: string, y: number };

const arr1: (A | B)[] = [];
arr1.find(e => e.x === ""); // OK
arr1.map(e => e.x); // OK

const arr2: A[] | B[] = [];
arr2.find(e => e.x === ""); // OK
arr2.map(e => e.x); // Error: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.
```

Shouldn't this `arr2.map(e => e.x)` work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This currently does not work. Since the methods of `A[]` and `B[]` have different signatures if you put them in a union the corresponding method will be a union of the original signatures and thus not invokable.

This restriction will be relaxed in a future version of typescript as described [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29011) (possibly in the January 2019 release). With the changes outlined there your example should work as expected, but at this time I have not tested this.

In the meantime your best solution is to use a type assertion:

```
(arr2 as (A | B)[]) .map(e => e.x);
```